# Can anyone help me find out where I made a mistake?

Tags: python, loops, primes

I am trying to figure out how to print a requested amount of prime numbers but I am having problems.

I can't describe what I did so I'll just paste my code so far:

```
requested_primes = 3 #just for simplicity, i am going to request an input for how many prime integers they  #want printed
found_primes = 0
examined_number = 2 #starting point for counting

while found_primes != requested_primes: #self-evident i hope
    for i in range(2, examined_number): #trying to check if it's a prime number or not with this one.
        if examined_number % i == 0: #if it can be neatly divided, it's not a prime and the search has to go    #on
            examined_number += 1
        else: #if no neat divisions can occur then i got a prime number and i can print it before going back #and searching for another one, until found_primes == requested_primes
            print(examined_number, end=' ')
            examined_number += 1
            found_primes += 1
```

Nothing comes up in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems, both of which can potentially cause you to have infinite loop. First of all, you are starting with `range(2, 2)` - it has 0 elements, meaning your for loop will not do anything and you will stay in the while loop infintiely. Start from 3 and just assume 2 is prime.

Fixing this will still not make the code work, because you are increasing `examined_number` and `found_primes` **every time** number does not divide evenly. Which means your `found_primes` very quickly goes past `requested_primes` and you will stay in the while loop forever. In order to fix that, you can use that fact that `for` loop supports `else` clause that only happens if the loop finished normally - so we `break` if a number has divided evenly. If we didn't break, we run the else clause.

```
requested_primes = 10 #just for simplicity, i am going to request an input for how many prime integers they  #want printed
found_primes = 1
print(2, end=' ')
examined_number = 3 #starting point for counting

while found_primes != requested_primes: #self-evident i hope
    for i in range(2, examined_number): #trying to check if it's a prime number or not with this one.
        if examined_number % i == 0: #if it can be neatly divided, it's not a prime and the search has to go    #on
            examined_number += 1
            break
    else: #if no neat divisions can occur then i got a prime number and i can print it before going back #and searching for another one, until found_primes == requested_primes
        print(examined_number, end=' ')
        examined_number += 1
        found_primes += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop never runs due to `i` having the same starting value as `examined_number` (both are 2).

Try using `for in in range(1, examined_number)` and that should get your loop to execute - you can verify it is running by adding a few print statements

Comment: General code review - you have created an infinite loop by incrementing `examined_number` within the loop and not having a `break` statement. It's also worth considering if you need both a `while` and a `for` loop